# What is wrong with this attempt at solving Buffon's needle problem?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to complete a solution to Buffon's Needle Problem that my instructor started in class. I was able to solve the problem correctly with a different method but I'd like to know where this one is going wrong.

This version is the simple case when the needle length $l$ equals the spacing between the lines. The initial setup is shown in the link below (am not allowed to post pictures yet):

[Buffon Needle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQkm6.png)

When the centre of the needle is a distance $x$ from one of the lines, the angle $\theta$ between the needle and a perpendicular to the lines is

$$ \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{2x}{l} \right) $$

and the probability that the needle touches the line is

$$ \frac {2 \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{2x}{l} \right)}{\pi} $$

I integrated this from $x=0$ to $x=\frac{l}{2}$, using the substitution $u = \frac{2x}{l}, du = \frac{2}{l} \, dx$:

$$\begin{align} P &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{l}{2}} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{2x}{l} \right) dx \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{l}{2}\int_0^1 \cos^{-1} \left(u \right) \; du \\
&= \frac{l}{\pi}
\end{align}$$

I know the answer should just be $\frac{2}{\pi}$ and that it makes no sense for the answer to be dependent on $l$; it must have something to do with the $\frac{l}{2}$ that came out of the integral, but I just can't see where the mistake is.

Comment: You forgot to account for the sample space.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it; doesn't the $\pi$ in the denominator of my probability expression account for the sample space?

Comment: The $x$ is random and distributed uniformly over $[0,l/2]$. This has a constant probability density function, and that constant is not accounted for.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now; I accounted for the probability of the angle but not for the probability of the location of $x$, so I have to multiply the answer by $\frac{2}{l}.$